# Hand up and down with parrallax effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, parallax

I'm creating a landing page for a selfmade application (its for a schoolproject).
When you load the page you will see an animation that pops up an iphone in a wrist.

What i'm trying to do now is to create it with a parrallax effect. So when you scroll down, the hand will go down and when you scroll the hand will go back up based on your scrollspeed.

At the moment i made it work with some animations from animate.css but i want to step the game up by adding the parrallax effect.

Here you can see how it looks like at the moment
http://faces.jorendemaeyer.be

You guys have any idea's how i can do that?

Comment: here is a cool parralax plugin which might help, http://janpaepke.github.io/ScrollMagic/

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked out the [skrollr](https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr) library?  It works well and is easy to set up.  That github page as well as [Ihatetomatoes.com](https://ihatetomatoes.net/how-to-create-a-parallax-scrolling-website/) has some great tutorials and documentation to help get you started with whatever you might need.

Good luck!